# feathersjs prevent find after every create

Tags: mongoose, feathersjs

This feels like a daft question but searching just seems to pull up the featherjs docs. which I find incredibly difficult to make sense of until you understand everything and being a bit new to feathers (months rather than years), I don't.

I have an "after" "find" hook that works quite well that runs a maintenance operation given certain presets in a query and in the config (all sort of OK) but the problem is that the maintenance operation does several "create" operations on other services each of which seem to trigger another "find" these just fail the maintenance requirements and so just terminate the process without completing the maintenance.

I think all I need to do is make yet another hook as "after" "create" to prevent further "find" hooks triggering. But how, without fouling up the whole chain?

Is there a simpler way?
and why go this route - can we just prevent this inside the call to the create service?

it is a feathers-mongoose database,
on a windows local system,
JavaScript no typescript

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Is your after find hook applied globally? It sounds like it's firing on services that you don't want it to fire on. You can assign after hooks to individual services. Can you post code samples of a reduced case?

Comment: No not global. it is currently only added to one service (the one that currently is used to find the data from the associated mongoose collection. the maintenance operation calls from a separate API then manipulates the data from that before adding it. I'm beginning to think this is a async/await hell.

Comment: can you post sample code that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have had such an issue before. A hack that works would be to add a new param in your outgoing request from the `after find hook`.
Then create a check somewhere on the hook(an if statement to check if the param is set), meaning that this is the second time the request is being sent through to the hook.
I hope this makes sense, had you provided any code, I would have demonstrated.